# Alter auto-generated sequence

Tags: sql, unit-testing, postgresql, hsqldb

I use this to create auto-incremented id columns:

```
  id  BIGSERIAL                                -- psql
  id  BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY  -- hsql
```

Now in unit tests i'd like to reset those sequences between tests.

**Is this possible?**  I target PostgreSQL and HSQLDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TRUNCATE table RESTART IDENTITY;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-truncate.html
http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_truncate_statement

Comment: It seems HSQL also supports this, can you add the link to the docs? The answer will be complete then

Comment: On more thing: what if `table` is referenced by a second table via foreign keys?

Comment: Then the `TRUNCATE` statement will either `CASCADE` delete the records or fail, depending on your preferences.

Comment: but unfortunately this differs between PSQL and HSQL

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL, you can use the `pg_get_serial_sequence` function to discover the name of the underlying sequence used to maintain the auto-increment, and the `setval` function to then manipulate it, e.g. to make the sequence match the highest value in the table after manually inserting or deleting rows:

```
Select setval(
    pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'column_name'),
    (Select Max(column_name) From table_name),
    TRUE
);
```

The "true" is optional (default behaviour); it tells the sequence the value provided has been used, and to increment *before* providing the next value. See [the Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html)

On an empty table, you want the next value to be 1, but 0 is out of range, so you would pass FALSE:

```
 Select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'column_name'), 1, FALSE);
```

Comment: Note though that just resetting the sequence without cleaning out the records will soon lead to problems with already existing keys.

Comment: @deceze Indeed. Hence the first example I gave, which is useful for putting the sequence right after manually "messing around with" *some* of the data in the table, but not emptying it.